# VBA parse JSON empty data

Tags: json, excel, vba

I'm trying to parse some data to a sheet with VBA. My code work's fine when all data in the JSON are provided, but when there is no (team1)(name) or (team1)(id), I get an error of incompatible data.

The code is below! It wrote 3 or 4 lines of data before the error.

The JSON data is more below.

IS there any way to avoid registers that don’t have all data or just write an “empty” value when the data is null?

```
Dim jsonText As String
Dim jsonObject As Object, item As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Matchs")
jsonText = ws.Cells(1, 1)

Dim http As Object, JSON As Object

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

http.Open "GET", "getMatches.json", False

http.Send

Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)

i = 2

For Each item In JSON
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = item("id")
    ws.Cells(i, 2) = item("date")
    ws.Cells(i, 3) = item("title")
    ws.Cells(i, 5) = item("team1")("name")
    ws.Cells(i, 6) = item("team1")("id")

    i = i + 1
Next
```

The JSON =>

```
[{"id":2342835,"date":1594731600000,
   "team1":{"name":"FATE","id":9863},
   "team2":{"name":"Budapest Five","id":9802},
   "format":"bo1",
   "event":{"name":"Eden Arena Malta Vibes Cup 3","id":5426},
   "stars":0,"live":false},
{"id":2342836,"date":1594731600000,
   "team1":{"name":"PACT","id":8248},
   "team2":{"name":"Singularity","id":6978},
   "format":"bo1",
    "event":{"name":"Eden Arena Malta Vibes Cup 3","id":5426},
    "stars":0,"live":false},
{"id":2342843,"date":1594735200000,
    "title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group A Winners' Match",
    "stars":0,"live":false},
{"id":2342862,"date":1594735200000,
    "team1":{"name":"Nexus","id":7187},
    "team2":{"name":"BIG Academy","id":10254},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"Betano Masters Europe 2020","id":5427},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342834,"date":1594746000000,"team1":{"name":"sAw","id":10567},"team2":{"name":"Nexus","id":7187},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"ESEA Advanced Season 34 Europe","id":5415},"stars":1,"live":false},{"id":2342844,"date":1594746000000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group A Elimination Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342863,"date":1594750500000,"team1":{"name":"Unicorns of Love","id":9812},"team2":{"name":"Giants","id":4949},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"Betano Masters Europe 2020","id":5427},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342801,"date":1594751400000,"team1":{"name":"Secret","id":10488},"team2":{"name":"Tricked","id":4602},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"ESEA Advanced Season 34 Europe","id":5415},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342845,"date":1594756800000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group A Decider Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342803,"date":1594774800000,"team1":{"name":"Thunder Logic","id":9615},"team2":{"name":"RBG","id":10258},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"ESEA Advanced Season 34 North America","id":5416},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342864,"date":1594776600000,"team1":{"name":"Third Impact","id":10469},"team2":{"name":"Lethal Divide","id":10770},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"ESEA Advanced Season 34 North America","id":5416},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342816,"date":1594796400000,"team1":{"name":"Hard Legion","id":10421},"team2":{"name":"AGF","id":8704},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"Nine to Five 1","id":5409},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342817,"date":1594796400000,"team1":{"name":"Gambit Youngsters","id":9976},"team2":{"name":"ALTERNATE aTTaX","id":4501},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"Nine to Five 1","id":5409},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342818,"date":1594807200000,"title":"Nine to Five 1 Grand Final","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342837,"date":1594818000000,"team1":{"name":"HellRaisers","id":5310},"team2":{"name":"HONORIS","id":10737},"format":"bo1","event":{"name":"Eden Arena Malta Vibes Cup 3","id":5426},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342838,"date":1594818000000,"team1":{"name":"AGF","id":8704},"team2":{"name":"CR4ZY","id":10150},"format":"bo1","event":{"name":"Eden Arena Malta Vibes Cup 3","id":5426},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342846,"date":1594821600000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group B Winners' Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342847,"date":1594832400000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group B Elimination Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342848,"date":1594843200000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group B Decider Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342532,"date":1594890000000,"team1":{"name":"Rooster","id":9881},"team2":{"name":"Paradox","id":7983},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"LPL Pro League Season 5","id":5319},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342839,"date":1594893600000,"team1":{"name":"Gambit Youngsters","id":9976},"team2":{"name":"Lyngby Vikings","id":8963},"format":"bo1","event":{"name":"Eden Arena Malta Vibes Cup 3","id":5426},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342840,"date":1594897200000,"team1":{"name":"Illuminar","id":8813},"team2":{"name":"AVEZ","id":9797},"format":"bo1","event":{"name":"Eden Arena Malta Vibes Cup 3","id":5426},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342800,"date":1594899000000,"team1":{"name":"Mako","id":10507},"team2":{"name":"TRUCKERS WITH ATTITUDE","id":10713},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"LPL Pro League Season 5","id":5319},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342849,"date":1594900800000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group C Winners' Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342850,"date":1594911600000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group C Elimination Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342851,"date":1594922400000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group C Decider Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342824,"date":1594962000000,"team1":{"name":"Invictus","id":7966},"team2":{"name":"D13","id":8607},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"Perfect World Asia League Summer 2020","id":5376},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342825,"date":1594971000000,"team1":{"name":"ViCi","id":7606},"team2":{"name":"Lucid Dream","id":8680},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"Perfect World Asia League Summer 2020","id":5376},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342826,"date":1594980000000,"team1":{"name":"TYLOO","id":4863},"team2":{"name":"Divine Vendetta","id":10396},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"Perfect World Asia League Summer 2020","id":5376},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342841,"date":1594980000000,"team1":{"name":"Hard Legion","id":10421},"team2":{"name":"SG.pro","id":10105},"format":"bo1","event":{"name":"Eden Arena Malta Vibes Cup 3","id":5426},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342842,"date":1594983600000,"team1":{"name":"ALTERNATE aTTaX","id":4501},"team2":{"name":"Syman","id":8772},"format":"bo1","event":{"name":"Eden Arena Malta Vibes Cup 3","id":5426},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342852,"date":1594987200000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group D Winners' Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342827,"date":1594989000000,"team1":{"name":"TIGER","id":10661},"team2":{"name":"Beyond","id":8262},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"Perfect World Asia League Summer 2020","id":5376},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342853,"date":1594998000000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group D Elimination Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342854,"date":1595008800000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Group D Decider Match","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342855,"date":1595059200000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Quarter-Final #1","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342828,"date":1595062800000,"title":"PAL Summer - Semi-final #1","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342856,"date":1595070000000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Quarter-Final #2","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342829,"date":1595073600000,"title":"PAL Summer - Semi-final #2","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342857,"date":1595080800000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Quarter-Final #3","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342858,"date":1595091600000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Quarter-Final #4","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342830,"date":1595149200000,"title":"PAL Summer - 3rd Place Decider","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342859,"date":1595152800000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Semi-Final #1","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342831,"date":1595160000000,"title":"PAL Summer - Grand Final","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342860,"date":1595163600000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Semi-Final #2","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342861,"date":1595174400000,"title":"Malta Vibes 3 - Grand Final","stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342643,"date":1597134600000,"team1":{"name":"Ground Zero","id":8536},"team2":{"name":"Paradox","id":7983},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"ESL Australia & NZ Championship Season 11","id":5318},"stars":0,"live":false},{"id":2342520,"date":1597147200000,"team1":{"name":"Bantz","id":10712},"team2":{"name":"TRUCKERS WITH ATTITUDE","id":10713},"format":"bo3","event":{"name":"ESL Australia & NZ Championship Season 11","id":5318},"stars":0,"live":false}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dictionary `Exists` method:

```
If item.Exists("team1") Then 

   If item("team1").Exists("name") Then 
       'record the name
   End If

End If
```